# Overriding Django allauth login form with ACCOUNT_FORMS

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-allauth

I already overrode the signup form with the simple settings variable `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` but to override the login form you need to use `ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'login': 'yourapp.forms.LoginForm'}`. I have the form I want and it displays perfectly with crispy-forms and Bootstrap3:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    login = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput, required = True)

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_show_labels = False
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Field('login', placeholder = 'Email address'),
        Field('password', placeholder = 'Password'),
        FormActions(
            Submit('submit', 'Log me in to Cornell Forum', css_class = 'btn-primary')
        ),
    )
```

When I submit the form I get `AttributeError at /account/login/ - 'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'login'`. What's going wrong here? The source for the original allauth login form is here: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py

Comment: The docs for allauth are here showing the setting: http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my understanding, you can overwrite the default LoginForm using `ACCOUNT_FORMS`, but you need to provide a class that contains all the methods provided in the original class. Your class is missing the `login` method.

I would set `ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'login': 'yourapp.forms.YourLoginForm'}` in your `settings.py` file, where `YourLoginForm` inherits from the original class.

```
# yourapp/forms.py

from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm

class YourLoginForm(LoginForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput()

        # You don't want the `remember` field?
        if 'remember' in self.fields.keys():
            del self.fields['remember']

        helper = FormHelper()
        helper.form_show_labels = False
        helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('login', placeholder = 'Email address'),
            Field('password', placeholder = 'Password'),
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Log me in to Cornell Forum', css_class = 'btn-primary')
            ),
        )
        self.helper = helper
```

Comment: This is essentially what I did but it's a nightmare/a path not worth going down because you have to copy essentially the whole, convoluted `LoginForm` class. It's not very extensible and is undocumented. In the end I just ditched Django and finished the app with Laravel.. best decision I made.

Comment: FYI to anyone reading this, this solution worked fine for me without having to copy anything else. Worked perfectly.

Comment: I keep getting circular imports doing this

Comment: @guival I also had this problem, where I was getting a circular due to SignupForm being in the same `forms.py`. I found this other solution which was to just give SignupForm its own file separate from loginform, and then update your `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` accordingly.  It fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945784/keeping-custom-sign-up-class-and-importing-allauth-forms-in-same-forms-py-file-c