# Django allauth custom login form not rendering all fields in custom user model

Tags: python, django, forms, django-allauth

I am trying to implement login of that consists a custom user model. Is it possible to inherit from `allauth.account.forms.LoginForm` and add a custom field to the custom login form?

> Idea is to assign user with a role at the time of login by overriding
>   login() method.

I have followed [allauth configuration](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) and mentioned what forms to use for login in settings.py with following code

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'core.forms.SignupForm'
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'login': 'core.forms.CoreLoginForm'}
```

I am using no auth backends other than `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` and `allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend`. custom signup is working fine for me without any issues. But ***custom loginform is not rendering all fields in the user model***. Allauth LoginForm was inherited as per accepted answer in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599186/overriding-django-allauth-login-form-with-account-forms) and a choicefield was added to the custom login form.

```
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm
class CoreLoginForm(LoginForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(CoreLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    role = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=User.roles, initial=User.roles[0])
```

Upon a `./manage.py runserver` it says `Module "core.forms" does not define a "SignupForm" class`. I have already defined a SignupForm in core.forms as below and `signup will work if  CoreLoginForm is inherited from forms.Form instead of LoginForm`. So if I do

```
class CoreLoginForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(CoreLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    role = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=User.roles, initial=User.roles[0])
```

I can render custom login form to html page. But problem here is that I have to redefine every methods in the class including `authenticate()`, `perform_login()` etc. This will end up in copying whole LoginForm and pasting it in forms.py of the app. I dont want to do this as I think this is against DRY principle. Is there a simple way to add a custom field to custom loginform and override login() method?

TIA

Answer (score 5):

Probably you have solved your problem already but i ll leave this solution for other guys who ve spent more then 10 minutes on this problem like me :)

I have found an easy way to add a field to Allauth login form:

As you have done - add to settings.py :

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'login': 'core.forms.CoreLoginForm'}
```

and after that in your forms.py you need to add :

```
from django import forms
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm

class CoreLoginForm(LoginForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CoreLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ## here i add the new fields that i need
        self.fields["new-field"] = forms.CharField(label='Some label', max_length=100)
```

Comment: There are a few ways to do this but I feel this is the most Python/Django way to go.  Good work/up vote deserved for solving and posting.